# pre-selected option ( Dropdown ) for Edit form in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i create a edit form for add-category in my site .

i need when enter the edit page it selected category value for dropdown .

**1 - i send the request to server for get detail :**

```
  public GetCatDetail(id:number){
    this.catService.GetCatDetail(id).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.cat=data,
    this.editCatFG.setValue({
      pFaName:[data.pFaName],
      pEnName:[data.pEnName],
      subCat:[data.subCat]
    }),
    this.selectedCat=data.subCat
  })
  }
```

**2- send a request to server for get category list to fill dropdown .**

```
 public GetAllCat(){
  this.catService.GetAllCatList().subscribe((data)=>{
  this.cats=data
  })
 }
```

**3- i fill the dropdown in html :**

```
    <select style="margin-right: 105px;" name="roleLevel" formControlName="subCat" [(ngModel)]="selectedCat">
                    <option  selected>    دسته اصلی </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let cat of cats" selectedCat="cat.id" [value]="cat.id" >{{cat.pFaName}}</option>
     </select>
```

I now need to select the value that exists for the categories in the databaseand selected that in the form in the dropdown.

how can i do this ?

Comment: this.selectedCat, is that of same type as cat.id used in the options?

Comment: @Aragorn yes . both of them is `number`

Comment: First mistake is you don't need to use formcontrol and ngModel both. Please use any one of them.

Comment: And for select dropdown in list I suggest you to see and try this module. This is very helpful to you and also it's very easy. ngx-select-dropdown

Comment: @SachinShah can you help me for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the array used for `options` list is of complex objects than just `string` or `number`, you need to use `ngValue`. 
Try this:

Update: Adding `compareWith` to select the default value

```
<select style="margin-right: 105px;" name="roleLevel" formControlName="subCat" [(ngModel)]="selectedCat" [compareWith]="compareById">
                    <option *ngFor="let cat of cats"  [ngValue]="cat" >{{cat.pFaName}}</option>
     </select>
```

In your component:

```
compareById(o1, o2) {
    return o1.id === o2.id
  }
```

If `cat.id = 0` is not coming from the service, you can add it to the array like this:

```
public GetAllCat(){
  this.catService.GetAllCatList().subscribe((data)=>{
  this.cats=data
  //adding the value for id=0;
  this.cats.push({id:0, pFaName: '    دسته اصلی '});
  })
 }
```

Comment: @kianoush can you create a stackblitz page for this?

Comment: Ok, try this document, might help you: https://medium.com/@kastepanyan24/how-to-set-selected-option-dynamically-in-angular-6-85c99958cca5

Comment: i am iranian . this site filter my country . and my country filter all of vpn :)))))

Comment: Updated my answer to use compareWith function, try that.

Comment: thanks man . its work but have little problem . when i need to select this : `<option >    دسته اصلی </option>` it not show any thing . when category id is `0` i need to select this

Comment: Updated to add cat.id = 0 item to the array.